# How to refresh a page for only one time using angular7?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I wants to refresh a page for only one time using **angular 7**.

I have tried below code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let win = (window as any);
  if (win.location.search !== ‘?loaded’ ) {
    win.location.search = ‘?loaded’;
    win.location.reload();
  }
}
```

but this code refresh the page continuously.
Please someone give me solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you store a flag in sessionStorage and refresh based on its value ? like, set the flag in sessionStorage before the refresh and if the flag is already there, then do not proceed with refresh. Please note that, sessionStorage will be cleared when the user closes the browser and refresh will happen every time  the user loads the page after closing, if you really want this ontime only then you can use localStorage